# Is there a way to retrieve logs not generated in Jenkins for a freestyle project using ExtentReports, Selenium, and Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, extentreports

in jenkins when run the freestyle project it show the blank report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDVbL.png)

-- i need all the log which run in my local machine but does not generate in the jenkins. also it generated the html file but it show blank white page.